# Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num' in Flutter's onChange method

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, payment, tostring

I'm encountering an error in my Flutter app when trying to log the Change object in the onChange method of my Cubit. The error message is as follows:

''''
`Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.`
''''

This error is pointing to the line where I'm logging the Change object using `log(change.toString());`. I understand that this error occurs because I'm trying to log a String as a num, which is not allowed in Dart.

I want to understand how to correctly log the Change object as a `String without encountering this error.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
@override
void onChange(Change<PaymentState> change) {
  log(change.toString()); // Error occurs on this line
  super.onChange(change);`your text`
}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error and correctly log the Change object as a `String in Flutter.

Feel free to use this question as a starting point, and make any additional clarifications or provide more context if necessary. Stack Overflow is a great platform for getting detailed answers to specific programming questions.

Comment: Likely, the TextField is a String.  And you have a num parameter... you'll need to use double.tryParse on the string to turn it into a number.

Comment: Like **pskink** suggested, find the definition of `log`. Clearly, it doesn't take a string as the first parameter. Does it take a log-level enumerator as the first parameter and a string as the second? Alternatively, is `log` supposed to find the log of a number?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz, I think he has imported log from math.dart instead of developer.dart.  please correct your import

Answer (score 0):

Your TextField is only accepting String value but you're passing num parameter,please Parse your parameter to the required data type.(num to string)

Comment: It looks like the opposite is true. He's passing a string and the first parameter to `log` is a number.