# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num' in Flutter's onChange method

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, payment, tostring

I'm encountering an error in my Flutter app when trying to log the Change object in the onChange method of my Cubit. The error message is as follows:

`Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'`

This error is pointing to the line where I'm logging the Change object using log(change.toString());. I understand that this error occurs because I'm trying to log a String as a num, which is not allowed in Dart.

I want to understand how to correctly log the Change object as a `String without encountering this error.

Here's the relevant code snippet:
'''

```
@override
void onChange(Change<PaymentState> change) {
  log(change.toString()); // Error occurs on this line
  super.onChange(change);
}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error and correctly log the Change object as a `String in Flutter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num' in Flutter's onChange method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77393426/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-num)

Comment: apparently this `log` function only takes `num` as argument. I don't know what you actually want to do but maybe you want `print` or `debugPrint` instead of `log`. In any case the error lies in this `log` function or the way that you are using it

Comment: Try to make sure of `import: dart:developer` instead of `dart:math`

Answer (score 0):

Use `debugPrint()` like `debugPrnt(change.toString())`

> Prints a message to the console, which you can access using the
> "flutter"  tool's "logs" command ("flutter logs").

---

**Edit**
`debugPrint(String?, {int? wrapWidth})` is a function of package:flutter/src/foundation/print.dart.

For dart use `print(Object? object)`

> Prints a string representation of the object to the console.